# How to set default value and label together for SelectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a simple selectOneMenu

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="signer" value="#{Bean.signer}"
                 required="true">
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@this"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="choose signer" itemValue="#{null}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.signers}" var="signer"
                 itemLabel="#{signer.fullname}" itemValue="#{signer}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

In my case the first selectItem displays message but it doesn't have any value `#{null}`.
But I need a label as first item, and set the default value (the first item from list signers)
How I can do this two actions together?

Comment: What do you mean with "message"? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I mean the text that displays on bar as first element. itemLabel="choose signer". And also i need ability to set the default value (for example first element from list).

Comment: Simply set `#{Bean.signer}` in your bean. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468667/jsf-bean-property-initialization. Also, you seem to be missing a converter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/conversion-error-setting-value-for-null-converter-why-do-i-need-a-converter.